# Github denies access for "Duffy". Where does the name Duffy come from?

Tags: git, github

I manage 2 user accounts in github. One for Tweety another one for Duffy.
When I push a repo owned by Tweety, I get the message

```
Persmission to rep-name denied: to Duffy.
```

I use putty generated keys that I registered for Tweety. Why does github think I am Duffy? Is there any configuration file that could hold this name? In my local git config there is nothing about Duffy.

remote config:

```
[remote "origin"]
url = https://github.com/tweety/www.git
puttykeyfile = tweety.ppk
```

Comment: How is your remote configured?

Comment: Added remote to the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An http credential was stored inside the Windows Credential Manager. Deleting it caused a browser windows come up upon next push, where I logged in as Tweety. Push succeded.

answer provided by github support, thx.